# XQuery : OBJECT_VALUE invalid identifier

Tags: oracle11g, xquery

I've created a table

```
Movie ( title varchar2(40), review XMLTYPE)
```

And review has: `

```
<review>
<reviewer>...</reviewer>
<title> ....</title>
<rating>.....</rating> </Review> </reviewer>
```

When I try to access :

```
SELECT X.reviewername FROM movie m, XMLTABLE ('for $d in /reviews/review 
return $d' 
PASSING OBJECT_VALUE
columns 
reviewername VARCHAR2(50) PATH 'reviewer') AS X
```

I get an error at OBJECT_VALUE. Where am I going wrong?

EDIT: I changed the Query to

```
SELECT m.title,
warehouse2.*
FROM movie M,
XMLTABLE('/REVIEW'
  PASSING m.reviews
  COLUMNS 
     "Rail" varchar2(60) PATH '//RATING') 
  warehouse2;
```

But no rows are getting selected. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well for one thing, don't you have a typo: '/reviews/review ' ? there is no element called <reviews> anywhere in your example.  Can you clean-up the code so that it is accurate?

Comment: Tried changing it to lowercase. Still, does't return any rows.

Comment: Your XML isn't well formed, you have overlapping tags, you have mismatched reviews/Reviews (XML is case sensitive) and in your query you have reviews/review but your xml has /review (no s on the end).

Answer (score 0):

> Well for one thing, don't you have a typo: '/reviews/review ' ? there is no element called  anywhere in your example.
>
> Your XML isn't well formed, you have overlapping tags, you have mismatched reviews/Reviews (XML is case sensitive) and in your query you have reviews/review but your xml has /review (no s on the end). –